# Concatenate whitespace character to field value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can i append a whitespace character- for example &#160; / &#xa0; (non-breaking space) to a field value querying oracle server?

I tried

```
SELECT myfield || '&#160;' FROM mytable
```

but this is interpreted as a variable with the name #160.

Comment: This will only happen in SQL*Plus, where "&" is interpreted as the start of a variable (see Dougman's answer). Where will you be running this SQL when part of your application?

Comment: @Nick - It will be part of a sproc inside a package. It tested using plsql developer. I think the best solution will be to use CHR() like Dougman and Jeffrey suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command

```
set define off
```

to prevent Oracle from using the `&` to denote a variable substitution.

Of course that just keeps it from keying off the & symbol.  You could use the `chr( )` function to insert a character with that binary equivalent value that you want.

Answer (score 2):

simply doing

```
select sysdate || ' ' from dual
```

works for me.  Does this not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [CHR](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions18a.htm#SQLRF00616) function:

```
SELECT myfield || CHR(160) FROM mytable
```

Comment: Yes CHR() is the best way to accomplish what i needed. Dougman just was a bit faster ;-)

Comment: well, that's your choice, no worries :)